# How to navigate from a navigation view to another navigation view with button click in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to navigate from one navigation view to another with button click. The flow should be Content View -> Login View -> Password View. I successfully navigated from Content to Login by appending to navigation path, but when I tried to do the same within Login View to go to Password, it doesn't work. Is this the right way to navigate between views? I am not sure why the following doesn't work for Login -> Password.

```
   ... Content View
   @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ZStack {                    
                ...some view
                Button(action: {path.append("LoginView")}) {
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                                    .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                                    .background(.white.opacity(0.5))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .clipShape(Circle()).padding(.top, 580)
                            }.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                                if view == "LoginView" {
                                    LoginView()
                                }
                                else {
                                    PasswordView()
                                }
                            }
            }
        }
    }

// login page
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
              NavigationStack {
                ZStack {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {path.append("PasswordView")}) {
                            Text("Continue")
                                .padding(.horizontal, 125)
                                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                                .foregroundColor(Color("DarkGreen"))
                                .background(Color("PrimaryGreen"))
                                .cornerRadius(25)
                        }.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                                if view == "PasswordView" {
                                    PasswordView()
                                }
                            }
                    }
               }
            }
          }
    }


// password page
struct PasswordView: View {
    @State private var password: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
               ...password view
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach where you have only **one** `NavigationStack` and a `binding` to control which `View` you want to display:

The reasons it `does not work` with your current code is because you have multiple
`NavigationView` (which are deprecated BTW), and multiple `NavigationStack` to display
the desired Views. Use just one `NavigationStack`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            ZStack {
                Text("ContentView")
                Button(action: {path.append("LoginView")} ) {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                        .frame(width:30, height: 30)
                        .background(.white.opacity(0.5))
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .clipShape(Circle()).padding(.top, 580)
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { view in
                    if view == "LoginView" {
                        LoginView(path: $path)  // <--- here
                    }
                    else {
                        PasswordView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {path.append("PasswordView")}) {
                    Text("Continue")
                        .padding(.horizontal, 125)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PasswordView: View {
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("PasswordView")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in LoginView you have forgotten to add path in NavigationStack and because of that it is not executing destination code

Change code of

```
NavigationStack { ...}
```

to

```
NavigationStack(path: $path) {
... Your code
}
```

Hope that helps!